# Wordpress How to create a Fade away success message after submission of form?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom form in a wordpress page. After successful submission of the form, I want to be in the same page (i.e. a blank form submission page) with a success message near the Submit button.

For now I am using

```
header("Location: http://localhost/gazz/submit", true, 301);
```

which redirect me to the same page with blank feild.
How do I add a success message which will display and then fade away?

Comment: Do you want a php flash message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parameter on your redirect link

```
header("Location: http://localhost/gazz/submit?submitted=offcourse", true, 301);
```

Then spit out something when that parameter is found,

add something like this on the same page

```
if ( isset( $_GET['submitted'] ) && $_GET['submitted'] == 'offcourse' ) { ?>
    <div class="my-very-cool-and-so-awesome-notification">
        <p> Thank you for using the form. Happy New Year</p>
    </div>
    <script>
    ( function($) {
        $(document).ready( function() {
            var notification = $('.my-very-cool-and-so-awesome-notification');
            if ( notification.length ) 
            setTimeout( function() {
                notification.addClass('fadeaway');
            }, 10000) // add class after 10 seconds
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <style>
    .my-very-cool-and-so-awesome-notification {
        max-height: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
        overflow: hidden;
        webkit-transition: all .45s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all .45s ease-in-out;
         -ms-transition: all .45s ease-in-out;
          -o-transition: all .45s ease-in-out;
             transition: all .45s ease-in-out;
    }
    .my-very-cool-and-so-awesome-notification.slideup {
        max-height: 0;
    }
    .my-very-cool-and-so-awesome-notification.fadeaway{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```